# Usage of hasNextInt() in java

Tags: java

I am a beginner and I am confused with using     hasNextInt(). If it checks the input, then shouldn't we be using it **after** asking the user for input?  However, in the given code below, it is used with     if statement. Please advise.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public  class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your number");
        if (userInput.hasNextInt()) {
            int numberEntered = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.println("You entered an integer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("you didn't enter an integer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `hashNextInt` says whether the next input can be safely read as an `int` so it only make sense to call it before you get an error attempting to read something which is not an `int`.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable in Java, but to me this looks fine. You print `Enter your number`, and then wait for the user input. If it's an int then you react to it. I believe that with `Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);` you start waiting for input. `if (userInput.hasNextInt())` only checks the last (oldest, I'd guess) input from the user, which is stored in a buffer. Read more about how `import java.util.Scanner` and input/output works in Java to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use it to test the user's input, so you are sure that when you call nextInt you won't have an exception because the input wasn't an int, it's also not moving he cursor forward:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The java.util.Scanner.hasNextInt() method returns true if the next
> token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in
> the default radix using the nextInt() method. The scanner does not
> advance past any input.

So Scanner would be invoked upon user presses "Enter" and then it would evaluate if the next input provided by user is int or not.

Comment: Can you please clarify it more?

Comment: Peter has explained it better -hashNextInt says whether the next input can be safely read as an int so it only make sense to call it before you get an error attempting to read something which is not an int