# How do I properly use the hasNextInt method as an if statement logical statement

Tags: java, if-statement, input

I'm a beginner at Java and there's something puzzling me about my code. In the assignment, I'm supposed to, as the assignment requests:

> "Make sure the user has entered a valid integer value. Write an if()
> statement as follows: Use the Scanner hasNextInt() method in the
> logical expression to get a Boolean value"

However, whenever I insert the `Input(Scanner name).hasNextInt` as the `if` statement's logical expression, my console does not print the factorial. What am I supposed to do in order to be able to use the `hasNextInt` method properly?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorials {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //1. create variables
        int num = 1;
        
        //2. Input prompt 
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer number and press Enter: ");
        num = Input.nextInt();
        
         if (Input.hasNextInt()) { 
                
                //for() loop
                long fact = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) { 
                    fact = fact * i;
                }
                System.out.println("for() loop result: " +fact);
                
                //while() loop
                fact = 1;
                int i = 1;
                while (i <= num) { 
                    fact = fact * i;
                    i++;
                }
                System.out.println("while() loop result: " +fact);
                
                // do while() loop
                fact = 1;
                i = 1;
                do {
                   fact = fact * i;
                   i++;
                } while(i <= num);
                System.out.println("do-while() loop result: " +fact);
                
                Input.close();
                return;
         }
         else {
                
                System.out.println("The text you entered was either not a number or is not an integer, please try again.");
                
                Input.close();
                return;
        }// end of if
         
    
    }// end of main

}// end of class
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your Code: all I did is  moved  `num = Input.nextInt();` in `if statement`

```
        int num = 0;
        
        //2. Input prompt 
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number that is an integer: ");
        
         if (Input.hasNextInt()) { 
             num = Input.nextInt(); // changed  
                long fact = 1;
                for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
                    fact = fact * i;
                }
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("The factorial of "+num+" is: "+fact);
                
                
                Input.close();
                return;
         }
            else {
            
            System.out.println("The text you entered was either not a number or is not an integer, please try again.");
            
            Input.close();
            return;
            }
```

output:

```
Please enter a number that is an integer: 5

The factorial of 5 is: 120
```

[You can refer this to know more about hasNextInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800872/usage-of-hasnextint-in-java)